# System.unauthorizedaccess while running .NET setup and deployment application

Tags: c#, .net, setup-deployment

I have a small [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) application deployed using "Setup and Deployment" wizard. The problem is that when I run it with the user having administrator rights, it runs without any errors, and if the user doesn't have administrator rights then it gives the error

> Application encountered an error and needs to close

When I check the error report, it says:

> P9: System.unauthorizedaccess

I even checked the option "Install to Everyone", but to no use.

What might be the issue?

Comment: Start by writing an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and log or display the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString().  Now you can ask a real question instead of "it doesn't work, why?"  UAC is the typical cause.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Vista and Windows 7, you need to run/install as administrator for certain applications. You can turn off [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control). See *[Turn User Account Control on or off](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Turn-User-Account-Control-on-or-off)*.

The user can instructed to run as administrator if the user is not running as administrator. 
You can use the WindowsIdentity .NET class to get the user access level. See *[How to check if the logged on user is an administrator?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/54fb4e57-357e-4db9-a3e2-1c093a582926/)*.